# ng-src is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app using Ionic Framework 1 & AngularJS

I have REST service returning JSON data. The data is a photo album which consists of a name and an array of images in the album. I would like to use nested ng-repeat to display the albums and their photos in a view.

**My system info:**

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Distributor ID: LinuxMint Description:  Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca 
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

**View**

```
<!-- ng-repeat photo albums -->
    <div ng-repeat="album in albums" id="event-images">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <i class="ion-images"></i>
            {{ album.albumName }}
        </div>

        <a class="item item-list-detail">
            <ion-scroll direction="x">
              <img ng-repeat="image in album.images" ng-src="{{image.img-id}}" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb">
            </ion-scroll>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**JSON**

```
[

{
    "albumName": "Business School 2016",

    "images": [{
            "img-id": 1,
            "img-src": "http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 2,
            "img-src": "http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 3,
            "img-src": "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 4,
            "img-src": "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/12/19/2429637D00000578-0-image-a-284_1419003100839.jpg"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "albumName": "Summer School 2016",

    "images": [{
            "img-id": 1,
            "img-src": "http://nehandaradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Evan-Mawarire-outside-Harare-Magistrates-Court.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 2,
            "img-src": "http://resources0.news.com.au/images/2015/03/31/1227286/010588-3399e81e-d282-11e4-a5b4-b2d65ac8975a.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 3,
            "img-src": "http://nehandaradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/riot-police-at-mawarire-court-hearing.jpg"
        },

        {
            "img-id": 4,
            "img-src": "http://placehold.it/300x300"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

**Result upon running**

[So ng-repeat is correctly iterating over the 2 albums & 4 images in each but the images are not displaying, upon inspecting elements, ng-src="0"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJ8h.png)

So ng-repeat is correctly iterating over the 2 albums & 4 images in each but the images are not displaying, upon inspecting elements, ng-src="0". What's going on & how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be `ng-src="{{image['img-src']}}"` not `ng-src="{{image.img-id}}"` in your `img` tag.

You were passing wrong property and you also need to use bracket notation because of the hyphen in the property name.